# Laravel : Redirections in a subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel

I'm working on a local version of a website developed with Laravel. I have a URL like : http://localhost/s/SEO/userinstall which returns a 404 error. In the app/Http/routes.php , I tried the following but I'm still getting the same error :

```
Route::get('userinstall', 'InstallController@userinstall');
Route::post('userinstall', 'InstallController@saveUser');
```

Then I tried

```
Route::get('s/SEO/userinstall', 'InstallController@userinstall');
Route::post('s/SEO/userinstall', 'InstallController@saveUser');
```

I checked the *AllowOverride* directive in the Apache configuration file and it seems to be fine :

```
<Directory />
   AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

I'm using the defaut Laravel .htacess file. Any idea how I can fix this?

Thanks

Comment: have you checked http://localhost/public/s/SEO/userinstall ?

Comment: @PhInside I have no "public" folder in my installation.

Comment: More details and information are obviously needed. What does the vhost configuration look like? What's the path for your app? Why doesn't your Laravel installation have a public folder?

Comment: @JoachimMartinsen I'm on a local computer running OpenSUSE. The absolute path to the application is /srv/www/htdocs/s/SEO. I'm updating the post.

Answer (score 1):

By looking into your URL, http://localhost/s/SEO/userinstall

I am assuming s->SEO are directories under an apache root directory and because that you have to use "s/SEO/userinstall" in `Route::get('s/SEO/userinstall', 'InstallController@userinstall');`

You should Add the Apache Configuration of your website path `"../s/SEO"` assign a specific domain name. Such as `http://sandbox.local` such that you could access the site from `http://sandbox.local/userinstall`

That way, you could access the route by using

```
Route::get('userinstall', 'InstallController@userinstall');
```

Try to google it, to get an idea about, how you could setup your project to access through local domain.

Here is the URL which might help you. http://headsigned.com/article/setting-up-local-development-domain-with-apache-vhosts

Comment: Thanks for the turnaround. It did help a lot but I would like a more definite solution in case I want my website to be in a subfolder (domain.com/website)